# The "of" in "the month of January"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Why is it called 'the month of January' and not 'the month January'? As I was learning German, I noticed they used the latter (der Monat Januar). Why the discrepancy?

Comment: Excellent question! (I've absolutely no idea why).

Comment: In German, how do they say *The Year of the Dragon*?

Comment: In French they say what is the equivalent of the month of January (*le mois de janvier*) and there's been at least as much of French influence [since 1066](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_English_language#Middle_English_.E2.80.93_from_the_late_11th_to_the_late_15th_century) in the English language as German !

Comment: It is not just *the month of January*, but also *the season of winter* and such.  **Similarly in Romance,**
 where you have *el mes de enero* and *la estación de inverno* in Spanish, *il mese de gennaio* and *la stagione de’inverno* in Italian, and so and so forth. // Which brings to mind the unrelated question of why we bother to capitalize the names of months given that we no longer do so with seasons. In Spanish and Italian you do neither, while in Portuguese, you capitalize months as though they were French when in Portugal, but leave them lowercase in Brazil as though they were Spanish.

Comment: Why do we say "the Sea of Galilee", "the Gulf of Mexico", "the Gulf of California", "the Cape of Good Hope", and "the Lake of the Woods"?

Comment: @PeterShor ... because we are talking about _Galilee's sea, Mexico's gulf, California's gulf, Good Hope's cape, and Woods' lake_?

Comment: @coleopterist, Well, kinda, except Mexico, for example, has a few gulfs. There's no obvious reason why one should be Mexico's Gulf and the others not. For that matter, there is no place called "Good Hope" that might be the metaphorical owner of the Cape of Good Hope.

Comment: Why was etymology part of this question struck off? Now that I think of it, we can reword 'my pencil' into 'pencil of mine' and 'neighbour's house' as 'house of neighbour'. And also, appositive structures 'the city of New York' and 'month of January' can be changed into 'New York city' and 'January month' (the latter clumsily). Is this coincidence or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct:

> The month, January, is the first month of the year.
>
> The month of January is the first month of the year.

In the first case you do need the commas to indicate a parenthetical explanation. Without them you have two nouns together, and nouns don't qualify nouns. An adjective would work, but neither *month* nor *January* have a corresponding adjective.

In the second case we have a special case of genitive called the [genitive of apposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition#Appositive_genitive). It has the same meaning as the first. The second noun restricts and clarifies the other. A wordy explanation would be to replace the "of" with "that is to say", viz:

> The month, that is to say January, is the first month of the year.

It isn't particularly common in English to use the genitive this way, but that is the particular syntactic structure being used here.

Comment: Hmm, it sounds satisfactory. But is 'that is to say' a good replacement for 'of'? To my ears, 'that is to say' brings an approximate rewording of phrases before and after. Here, it should mean month is understood to be January (through context?) but is explained more clearly using 'that is to say'.

Comment: Honestly, that is an artifact of my Greek, which uses the genitive of apposition more commonly. This is a common suggestion to convey the meaning into English. You might be right, the point really is that "January" is a clarification of the word "month" not an addition to it. In a sense it "adjectivizes" the noun. (Don't you just love that new verb :-)

Comment: I approve your question, if only to put a comma here. Appositive genitive seems to pervade any language that I touch!

Answer (score 0):

I'm no authority on this, but the etymology for the month names may provide a hint:

January etymology probably comes from "Janus" -- a Roman deity; so if it meant "The month of Janus" that may make more sense. [1](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/January)

February also had a similar etymology; "Month of purification"[2](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/February);

It breaks down once we get to the months named after numbers (sept/oct/nov/dec), though.

I've often wondered why we named our last few months incorrectly (october isn't the eight month), but that's a separate issue, isn't it :)

Comment: I think the OP is asking about the "of" part.

Answer (score -2):

IMO, this is grammatically incorrect and a case of periphrasis gone wrong. But it has nevertheless *become acceptable* through regular use. It should be *the month, January* and *the season, winter* rather than *the month **of** January* or *the season **of** winter* just as it is the *year 2013* rather than *the year of 2013*.

The use of the preposition *of* alongside a noun usually indicates possession. Phrases such as *the PM of Djibouti* or *the admiral of the fleet* can be restated as *Djibouti's PM* or *the fleet's admiral* respectively. This doesn't really work with *the month of January* as *January's month* does not compute.

Moreover, *the admiral of the fleet*  sounds far more prestigious than the less flowery *fleet's admiral*. I suspect that the use of the verbose *month of January* came about for similar reasons. Even the presence of the word *month* in the phrase is often superfluous.

Comment: Not an expert, but wouldn't it require a comma as in "the month, January" to make it grammatically correct that way?

Comment: I think the contrast between Romance usage and Germanic usage, given above, is a far better starting point for speculation. According to ngrams (http://tinyurl.com/b4vdrvu) "month of X" phrases have been declining in use, not increasing, over the last 200 years or so.

Comment: @Ryan You're welcome to add an answer :) ... and what does the NGram prove?

Comment: @coleopterist, the NGram wasn't to prove anything, really. You wrote, "But it has nevertheless become acceptable through regular use." If that's true, and so is the NGram, then it must have become acceptable some time ago, but usage has been declining for 200 years, apparently.